# Pull Ad groups and count the users inside each group

Tags: powershell

I want to pull all AD groups in an OU and then print out each group and the user count thats in that group. The way I currently have it, it just counts how do I get the group name with the count of members?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$groups = (Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq 'security'} -SearchBase 'Path to OU' | select SamAccountName).samaccountname
foreach ($group in $groups){
(Get-ADGroup -Identity $group | select name).count
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `members` attribute, and count that one.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq 'security'} -SearchBase 'Path to OU' -Properties *
foreach ($group in $groups) {$group.members.count}
```

Or, since you want both,

```
$groups | select name, {$_.members.count}
```